# merge/concatenate x columns with x columns in the same dafarame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to combine a part of the columns from the dataframe with another part on the principle given in the screenshot. I have tried the pd.concat, pd.merge functions but I can't adjust them this way. Below I am posting a portion of the dataframe.
The target I would like is that when there is a result in both parts it will select one of them based on the condition.

[image]

```
            ('C1Cs')    ('C1Co')    ('C1Cg')    ('C1Cmp')   ('C1Xs')    ('C1Xobs')  ('C1Xg')    ('C1Xmp')
HERS00GBR   38.05       684.0       3.2         0.0         Nan         Nan         Nan         Nan
HUEG00DEU   Nan         Nan         Nan         Nan         46.26       27372.9     96.9        0.0
JFNG00CHN   43.19       2879.5      0.4         0.0         43.17       27143.9     31.6        0.0
JOZE00POL   40.03       645.0       4.8         0.0         Nan         Nan         Nan         Nan
KIR000SWE   33.66       727.5       4.7         0.0         Nan         Nan         Nan         Nan
KIRU00SWE   33.12       827.5       34.2        0.0         Nan         Nan         Nan         Nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `combine_first` (or `fillna`) the left part with the right part.

For this you need to slice and rename the right-hand columns:

```
half = len(df.columns)//2
rename_dic = dict(zip(df.columns[half:], df.columns[:half]))
out = df.iloc[:, :half].combine_first(df.iloc[:, half:].rename(columns=rename_dic))
```

output:

```
          ('C1Cs') ('C1Co') ('C1Cg') ('C1Cmp')
HERS00GBR    38.05    684.0      3.2       0.0
HUEG00DEU    46.26  27372.9     96.9       0.0
JFNG00CHN    43.19   2879.5      0.4       0.0
JOZE00POL    40.03    645.0      4.8       0.0
KIR000SWE    33.66    727.5      4.7       0.0
KIRU00SWE    33.12    827.5     34.2       0.0
```

*NB. first thing, ensure the NaNs are real NaNs and not 'Nan' strings: `df = df.replace('Nan', float('nan'))`*

If you want **in place** modification of your dataframe (i.e. no output but modifying your input dataframe directly), @JonClements suggested a nice alternative with `update` and `set_axis`:

```
df.update(df.iloc[:, -4:].set_axis(df.columns[:4], axis=1), overwrite=False)
```

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of: `df.update(df.iloc[:, -4:].set_axis(df.columns[:4], axis=1), overwrite=False)`

Comment: @Jon yes, nice shorter (in place) alternative :)  There are many similar ways with the same underlying logic. Regarding the copy/inplace, OP wasn't very clear on their expectations, unfortunately.

Comment: Feel free to add it in if you want - at least then OP has alternatives and they're all in one answer :)

Comment: @Jon I assumed you wanted so (else you can rollback and add your own!)

Comment: For your approach - I'm sure you can make use of `.set_axis` there and skip the `rename_dic` bit...